# Problemas de animacoes

Tags: html, css

Boas eu estou com um problema na responsivididade da minha pagina web devido a navbar.
Na navbar quando o ecrã tem menos de 540px de largura a navbar fica com o dropdown mas o meu problema é que o content da dropdown fica sobreposto por outro div como podem ver aqui

http://casimirowebshare.000webhostapp.com/nutrirossio/produtos.php

ja tentei meter a posição do div em relative e resulta mas todos as animacoes que tenho na pagina fica sem animacoes , assim :

```
.dropdown-content {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}
.artigos_para_venda{
   z-index: -1;
   position: relative;
}
```

http://casimirowebshare.000webhostapp.com/nutrirossio/contactos.php

Alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Faça um [mcve], por favor.

Comment: ja ta @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Tendo que acessar um link externo e para saber o código precisaria acessar o código fonte e analizar uma página inteira de HTML. Por quê não simplifica isso e reproduza o problema utilizando o snippet do SOpt?

Comment: como assim @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @RafaelCasimiro cara, e se você não usar `display: absolute;` no `.dropdown-content`, porque irá acabar resultando no mesmo visual.

Comment: @lucas mas se eu tirar  display: absolute; a dropdown nao ira ficar por cima do div

Comment: @RafaelCasimiro não precisa ficar por cima, apenas em seguida

Comment: @lucas para mim é preciso

Comment: @RafaelCasimiro pensa bem, se você deixar `absolute` vai cobrir o pesquisar e o titulo.

Comment: @lucas mas é isso que eu quero